# Xamarin forms, trying to bind my Image URL from my database to XAML but an image does not appear

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try to get an image from my database (in this case localhost) but it doesn't seem to work. I'm binding the result (URL to the image) to my XAML without any luck. I get no error but an Image does not appear either. This is my code.

Maybe it has something to do with my URL?
When I used parse (as backend) they gave us a URL that started like this:
"http://files.parsetfss.com/....."

My URL just starts with "localhost". Do I need to adjust the backend code somehow?

My cs file where I retrieve the http and jsondata:

```
static public async Task<JObject> getImages ()
{
    var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();
    var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://www.localhost.com/image.php");
    var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
    var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

    return jsonResult;
}
```

It looks like this on the localhost:

```
{
    "results": [
    {
        "GetImage": {
            "ID": 1,
            "Name": "Aqua",
            "URL": "http://localhost.com/Images/Aquavit.jpg"
        }
    }]
}
```

This is my contentpage where I try to recieve the image:

```
async void clickHere (object s, EventArgs ar)
{
    var createImage = await phpApi.getImages ();
    list = new List<pictures> ();

    foreach (var currentItem in createImage["results"]) {
        var prodPic = "";
        if(currentItem["GetImage"] != null)
        {
            prodPic = (string)currentItem ["GetImage"]["URL"];
        }

        list.Add (new pictures () { 
            image = prodPic,
        });

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (currentItem ["GetImage"]["URL"]); //here I get the exact URL.

    }
}
```

My class:

```
public class pictures 
{
    public string image { get; set; }
}
```

And its XAML:

```
<Image Source = "{Binding image}" />
```

Comment: I don't think you can set a string as an `Image.Source`... I'm not posting this as answer since I haven't tried it, but try making your `image` property of type `Uri` and change: `image = prodPic;` on your `list.Add` to something like: `image = new Uri(prodPic)`

Comment: I have worked with the same method before (when I used parse as my backend) with a string and that works.

Comment: I see, it seems it does work on Xamarin (just checked the docs)... I can't help you further then. If this was WPF I'd say your `pictures` class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (and the bound datacontext list `INotifyCollectionChanged`) and would tell you to check the `DataContext` on the Image, but I'm unsure how all this works in Xamarin, so I can't give any further tips without risking saying something stupid.

Comment: I tried your solution as well but with the same outcome. I appreciate the help though!!

Comment: I think there are some details you could add on this one. What platform is this happening on? In your case that works, is it also a jpg or a png? If you try using an image contained in the app instead, does it display correctly?

Comment: I am using Xamarin forms and I am recieving a JPG from localhost. When I use parse as a backend (that works) I use jpg and jpeg as well. When I use an image from my directory in Xamarin forms it works and I can see an image.

Comment: So is there nothing wrong with the code itself? Is it the URL or something like that?

Comment: when I am on my URL http link on my localhost I can zoom in but when I am on my parse URL it is "locked"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using a `UriImageSource` instead of string. Since it's a url. Try this:

your class:

```
public class pictures 
{
    public UriImageSource image { get; set; }
}
```

contentpage:

```
prodPic = (string)currentItem ["GetImage"]["URL"];

list.Add (new pictures () {
    image = new UriImageSource { Uri = new Uri(prodPic) },
});
```

Also I believe your list needs to be an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`.

Comment: Unfortunately same result as before.

Comment: weird.. have you tried with some random image on the web? instead of a localhost url

Comment: Yes I have and it still does not work. Very very strange. Tried with google pics, pics from "parse" etc. Same outcome.

Comment: after further review.. i believe your problem is that the list will never notify the UI thread.. try with an observerable collection

Comment: Like a propertychanged thing?

Comment: yeah but when working with lists its an ObservableCollection :)

Comment: Oh okay. I have not used that before. Do I have to create a viewmodel and such or is it more basic?

Comment: I dont believe you have to do that.. just change your list to an ObservableCollection<pictures> instead of list. I always work with the Mvvm pattern and therefor always use view models.. so thats the only way ive tried it..

Comment: I cannot find it. I assume I am missing an assembly?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%601/ try looking throught this.. there apparantly is something XAML specific.. i actually dont use XAML at all so i suggest you look there.. Hope you find your way ;)

Comment: list = new ObservableCollection <pictures> ();

Yeah I changed it now. Still no image though... hmm..

Comment: Works when I use my labels x:name and then put it source inside the loop. The binding apparently was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just in addition:

If you want to load more images and/or allow to display a placeholder while loading, I recomment the [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading) library. It offers nice functionality like downloading, caching, showing placeholder and error images and most important: down sampling the image to the target size. This is always a pain on android.

You can bind strings that contain urls directly to the `Source`. The code would like like:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage 
    Source="http://thecatapi.com/?id=MTQ5MzcyNA">
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```